# Sharing variables between objects / class properties

Tags: c#, ref

So I have a "world" object which contains a list of "tiles". I also have a "island" objects which contains certain "tiles" from the "world" objects list of "tiles". For external purposes I want to keep world and island as objects / classes.

I want to be able the change the values of the tiles in the list in world and for those changes to be observed in the tile class and vice versa.

Basically I want:

```cs
class World {
    List<Tile> tiles;
}

class Islands {
    // ref here is not syntax
    List<ref Tile> tiles;
}
```

But the `ref` is not allowed as a type argument in the list thingy. What is someway I can implement this behaviour while keeping them as close to be objects / class and not have duplicating tiles.

Comment: `Title` is already a *reference*, they can be referenced and shared anyway

Comment: Properties *are* the means to share data between *thingies* or objects and collections.  Your thingies however, do not show any properties.

Comment: As has already been inferred, if you create a new `Tile` object and add it to both your `World` and `Island` class lists, any changes you make to the tile will be seen in both classes.

Comment: Assuming that `Tile` is a class and not a struct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% clear on your requirements. But, if you want to share tiles, then both `World` and `Island` references will see changes in the values of those tiles automatically because they are sharing instances (which must be classes and not structs). This is *passive* though. If you need something to occur when these changes occur (e.g. telling `World` or `Island` to look and pay attention) then implement an event to be raised when the property changes.

If you need a complete replacement of a tile and want to observe that change then implement a layer of indirection; for example, a `TileReference` with a `Tile` property. When that property changes, you can raise an event, and a handler can observe the entirely new tile.